# File delete detection

Tags: java, file, file-io

Is there a good way to detect deletes in Java? I know I can loop through the contents of a folder and compare the previous results, but is there a better event driven way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no pure-java way to do what you describe. Here's [a project that uses the JNI to do filesystem monitoring on Windows and Lniux](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/), but I don't endorse it (I merely found it through google).

Answer (score 3):

I think this can interest You: [What is the easiest way to track a change in a folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031931/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-track-a-change-in-a-folder-in-java)

Comment: Specifically look here:  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6 but bear in mind this is Java 7 functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the Java 7 feature you'll be interested in (when it is properly available) is the [WatchService](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6).